# A good practice for using the spring security plugin with tokens

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-rest

I am making a REST api with spring boot and looking for a way to secure some of the api's. I also worked on another project where they used the grails spring security plugin (http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/2.0.0.M2/docs/index.html).

I want to work the exact same way, annotate the methods with the roles that can use them and so on. I find it difficult to find a tutorial to implement this way in spring boot. Or is there another very easy but secure way to do it?

(I use http so basis auth is not an option and I like the way the token is in te JSON response and then given with a header)

EDIT 5 sep

I searched a lot in the last 10 days and I found some tutorials but most of them are with spring and not spring-boot or they are not using annotations for controller methods. I also found JWT, it seems like a good idea but I still don't know how to combine it with spring-boot and annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very clear example after hours of searching. https://github.com/brahalla/Cerberus. It does exactly what I want.